# Blender installation wizard won't let me change the directory of installation

Tags: installation

I have 2 disks: 1 SSD with 120GB and dual-booted with ubuntu and windows 10, and a 2TB HDD partitioned into 1TB each for each OS.

In the installation wizard, even though I've set the install destination as 
the secondary partition HDD(D:/Blender), the wizard keeps on trying to install it onto my primary Disk, which is the SSD. 
[image]

[image]
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm going to guess that blender still needs space on C Disk, probably to install stuff for user preferences etc. In C:\Users\[User]\AppData  . . .

I recommend that you free up the required space on your C drive, 173 MB.

Comment: Use the zip version, that does not need to be installed and you can store it and run it from any directory/

Comment: @cegaton I've looked for it, but for some reason I couldn't find it. Would it be possible for you to provide me the link to the site? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.blender.org/download/ click on "other versions"

Comment: @cegaton Oh, it was the portable one! Thanks!